# How to nest a Location directive inside a virtual host config?

Tags: apache

I am trying nest a Location directive inside a virtual host config like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName mysite.com  
    DocumentRoot /home/deployer/apps/mysite/current/public  
    ErrorLog /var/log/prod.log  
    <Location "/shop">
        DocumentRoot /home/deployer/apps/mysite_shop/current/public  
        ErrorLog /var/log/prod.log  
    </Location>  
</VirtualHost>
```

What I want to do is go to mysite.com/shop, and point it to another application. Is this possible? Is there another method of doing this? I get an error because apparently Location directives do not accept DocumentRoot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this to work as a redirect?  If so, have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). If not, have a look at the [Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html).